# angular-datetimepicker is not refleting correct dates

Tags: angular, datetimepicker

I am new to the date/calendar on angular so any help will be greatly appreciated. I am trying to use angular-datetimepicker and was able to implement it. However, when I select any date from Oct 10- Oct31 and Dec 10 -Dec 31. The calendar minus 1 day on the date. E.g. if I select 2020-12-31, it will show 2020-12-30. This only happens to these month. I am not sure what is causing it. I have tried searching for it online but couldn't get any support. I even tried to play about with timezone but still no way. Please help. Below is the link to stackblitz.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datetimepicker?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdate-time-picker%2Fdate-time-picker.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

So it was something to do with timezone. Apparently, when the string was getting converted to Date, UTC was assumed. So I could either manually user date= new Date('2020-12-31 00:00') or

```
const datee = new Date(dateString);
const date= new Date(datee.getUTCFullYear(),
datee.getUTCMonth(),
datee.getUTCDate(),
datee.getUTCHours(),
datee.getUTCMinutes(),
datee.getUTCSeconds());
```

Hope this helps someone. Thanks